# Sales on Magento 2 Commerce store

Tags: magento2, magento2-enterprise, staging, lifetime-sales

Which features do you use/suggest to organize sale events on your Magento 2 Commerce stores?

Sale event is a period of time when some temporary changes are needed to be performed on the website. Normally the following points are changed:

- prices for some/all categories (using catalog price rules)
- banners/CMS blocks
- need a way to specify whenever sales is going on right now in the code (to be able to change something in custom webstore specific features)
- maybe product images

Looks like Content Staging is something that needs to be used in such cases.

Though does anyone have real experience of using that? I feel like there will can be some bottlenecks with size of database once it is used.

Answer (score 1):

This is little tricky question to answer and answer may vary depending on the stats ( site traffic, page views etc ) and platforms being used, when i say platform it mean both your servers and also framework ( magento CE, Magento EE ).

I suggest, whenever there is sale event you have to update everything ( like, banners, static content, price updates etc ) before sales occurs. Since after sales you would have lot of traffic on site and during that traffic you should not change anything on live site. because,In some cases you also need to run indexer to populate new products or sale prices. ( this is normally when you change product prices etc and these run lot of quries ).

NEVER run full indexer on site during / before sale , only run required indexer ( i.e product_stock_update, product_price etc this can chock your db server ).

Have spareate servers for database and web and do use redis to store sessions. otherwise your db will have lot of load. Use flat product / category this reduces db load too.

these are major things you need to do but again it always depends on size and platform being used.

Comment: "sale event you have to update everything" - this is what I would like to understand how to organise  better on Magento side to manage everything all together without overhead for webstore managers

Comment: @Roman, this is normal practice for westore managers and this is how it would be always ( update content and change product prices ), unless you have not setup any integration with their ERPs ( or inventory sync. ).